# using html to invisible the password in http request(link address bar)

Tags: html, http

html code:
 Password

password is invisible when the user inputs, but after submitting i can see the password in http request(link address), how to invisible the password in address bar too????
help!!

Comment: can anybody tell??

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using get method in your form and it's not a secure way.
any way you can use location.hash like below

```
jQuery(".submit-button").on("click", function () {
              location.hash = "hash";
             // alert("test");
    });
```

Comment: just started web development and html is the first chapter, cant relate too the jquery code. can you elaborate in html?

Comment: @mak use this in your <head> tag `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` then use my code above